# sheetPresentationController legacy for iOS 12 in Swift (Question)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, legacy

I'm have to extend the support for a Cocoapod made for target iOS 15, and works showing a UINavigationController as bottom modal, presented for a UIViewController

[image]

The problem is self.bottomController.sheetPresentationController is only available for iOS 15, and this must have to works until target 12.0

If I comment the line:

```
if let sheet = self.bottomController.sheetPresentationController {
    sheet.detents = [.large()]
}
```

and compile success for iOS 12 target, but the content of the modal is showed as fullscreen.

How can imitate or do something to show the content (red text) as modal, as the picture?

I tried using other pods into my pod but without success results. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

sheetPresentationController only work for ios 15 and later, for previously versions you need to set .custom modalPresentationStype

```
            controller.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
            if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {

                if let sheet = controller.sheetPresentationController {
                    sheet.detents = [.medium()]
                }
                
            } else {
                
                controller.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
                controller.transitioningDelegate = self
            }
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

// MARK: - UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

```
extension CPPdfPreviewVC: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {


func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
    PresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presenting: presenting)
    }
}
```

and Add Presentation controller as given

```
class PresentationController: UIPresentationController {

  let blurEffectView: UIVisualEffectView!
  var tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
  
  override init(presentedViewController: UIViewController, presenting presentingViewController: UIViewController?) {
      let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
      blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
      super.init(presentedViewController: presentedViewController, presenting: presentingViewController)
      tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissController))
      blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
      self.blurEffectView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
      self.blurEffectView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
  }
  
  override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
      CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.containerView!.frame.height * 0.4),
             size: CGSize(width: self.containerView!.frame.width, height: self.containerView!.frame.height *
              0.6))
  }

  override func presentationTransitionWillBegin() {
      self.blurEffectView.alpha = 0
      self.containerView?.addSubview(blurEffectView)
      self.presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) in
          self.blurEffectView.alpha = 0.7
      }, completion: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) in })
  }
  
  override func dismissalTransitionWillBegin() {
      self.presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) in
          self.blurEffectView.alpha = 0
      }, completion: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) in
          self.blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
      })
  }
  
  override func containerViewWillLayoutSubviews() {
      super.containerViewWillLayoutSubviews()
    presentedView!.roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 22)
  }

  override func containerViewDidLayoutSubviews() {
      super.containerViewDidLayoutSubviews()
      presentedView?.frame = frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView
      blurEffectView.frame = containerView!.bounds
  }

  @objc func dismissController(){
      self.presentedViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}

extension UIView {
  func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
      let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners,
                              cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
      let mask = CAShapeLayer()
      mask.path = path.cgPath
      layer.mask = mask
  }
}
```